# Issue with METHOD in prototype / Ajax.Request

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

I am trying to call yahoo api via Ajax to find current weather:

```
var query = "select * from weather.forecast where location in ('UKXX0085','UKXX0061','CAXX0518','CHXX0049') and u='c'";
var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) +'&rnd=1344223&format=json&callback=jsonp1285353223470';

new Ajax.Request(url, {
   method: 'get',
   onComplete: function(transport) {
      alert(transport.Status); // say 'null'
      alert(transport.responseText); // say ''
   }
});
```

I noticed, that instead of **GET** firebug says **OPTIONS**. What is it and how I can use force prototype to use GET?

Here is [functionality](http://www.zazar.net/developers/zweatherfeed/) which i am trying to recreate.

And here is full URL which I am trying to access:

`<a href="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%20in%20(%27UKXX0085%27%2C%27UKXX0061%27%2C%27CAXX0518%27%2C%27CHXX0049%27)%20and%20u%3D%27c%27&rnd=1344223&format=json&callback=jsonp1285353223470">http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%20in%20(%27UKXX0085%27%2C%27UKXX0061%27%2C%27CAXX0518%27%2C%27CHXX0049%27)%20and%20u%3D%27c%27&rnd=1344223&format=json&callback=jsonp1285353223470</a>`

Comment: Did you figure out why this happens? I'm having the exact same problems - no matter what I put in 'method', it only does 'OPTIONS' requests for some reason...

Answer (score 3):

After hours of trying to debug the same issue myself, I came to the following conclusion.

I believe this happens because of XSS counter-measures in newer browsers.

You can find very detailed information about these new counter-measures here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

Basically, a site can specify how "careful" the browser should be about allowing scripts from other domains. If your site, or a site from which you're loading external JavaScript code, includes one of these pieces of "browser advice", newer browsers will react by enforcing a stronger XSS policy.

For some reason, Prototype's Ajax.Request, under Firefox, seems to react by attempting to do an OPTIONS request, rather than a GET or POST, so perhaps Prototype has not been updated to correctly handle these new security conditions.

At least that was the conclusion in my case. Maybe this clue can help with your case...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I hope this will be useful for other users. I end up with iframe

Comment: Same here. If it is a Prototype issue, it's not been fixed in v1.7.

Comment: The problem is also on Chrome too (at least on v29)

Comment: In the case of YQL (and many other APIs by now) you can avoid XSS issues by using [JSONP](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/using-yql-with-jsonp/) - essentially, you ask the server to generate a script snippet invoking a given callback method-name. In other words, modern third-party services can "volunteer" control to your script by permitting you to specify a callback-method. (thus it's up to the service vendor to decide if they want to expose their API for client-side integration.)